# Groovy MarkupBuilder causing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on closure in soapUI

Tags: web-services, groovy, soapui

I am not able to get the Groovy MarkupBuilder to work with soapUI. I am very new to Groovy and I am just following one of the user guides on creating XML.

Testing a very simple method:

```
public String Example(){
def writer = new StringWriter()
def root = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
root.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version:"1.0", encoding:"UTF-8")
root.Root{
Example("A")
}
return writer.toString()
}
```

I get the following error in soapUI: ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MockXML$_Example_closure2

I have no error when I run from Groovy Console.

In the same class I have:
    public String Hello(){
    return "Hello"
    }

Which works fine in soapUI.

Is there something I would need setup/imported/configured in soapUI that I am not thinking about to handle MarkupBuilder/closures?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a syntax error in your markup.  I think:

```
root.Root {
```

should be:

```
root.Root() {
```

I think the Groovy evaluating your Root element as a closure instead of a new element in the markup.

Comment: That causes the same output in the Groovy Console and the same error in soapUI.

Comment: To further complicate things if I put code directly into soapUI instead of using the jar I created it works fine.